# Sand-boxing an application using strace

Tags: strace

I need to sand-box an untrusted user application. My idea was to use, among the other things, [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to intercept dangerous system calls.

Running:

```
strace APPLICATION
```

I get a list of the system calls performed by my application, but how can I disallow them?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using strace I'd recommend looking into something like a [chroot jail](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) instead for restricting a process.

Comment: I was actually thinking about using LXC combined with strace and other stuff, but I will look at that as well...